# PHPMailer to SMS - remove s: and m: prefixes

Tags: php, sms, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send text messages.  This is working.  However, the messages come with S: and M: at the begging of the messages. S: is for Subject and M: is for Message.

I've used both mail() and PHPMailer to send my messages.  Both methods include S and M.

My code is below.  How can I send messages with PHP without S and M showing up?

```
require('_includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');


// Instantiate Class
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set up SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;          // This will print debugging info
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      // Connect using a TLS connection
$mail->Host = "smtp.sparkpostmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';       // SMS uses 7-bit encoding

// Authentication
$mail->Username   = "username"; // Login
$mail->Password   = "password"; // Password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

// Compose
$mail->Subject = "";     // Subject (which isn't required)
$mail->Body = "Testing";        // Body of our message

// Send To
$mail->AddAddress( "myphonenumber@email.uscc.net" ); // Where to send it
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $mail->send() );      // Send!
echo '</pre>';
```

[image: Example of how messages are formatted on iOS]

Comment: It's not something you're doing, it's probably being done by by the uscc server.

Comment: What happens if you actually include subject text? Does it remove the prefix?

Comment: @JonStirling is there anyway to hide/remove it?

Comment: @Michael_B No, it still includes the prefix

Comment: I would try sending through another server. If the prefixes are gone, then @JonStirling may be correct.

Comment: @Michael_B The uscc.net server is for US Cellular which is my cell phone provider

Comment: I believe it's just one of those things. At a guess I suspect if you want it without those prefixes you'll need to use an actual SMS gateway provider.